# Why is Yaakov later willing to say אלוהי יצחק?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, words, avot-patriarch-fathers, shemos-sacred-names

In [Bereishit 31:42](http://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.31.42), Yaakov says

> אֱלֹהֵ֣י אָבִי֩ אֱלֹהֵ֨י אַבְרָהָ֜ם וּפַ֤חַד יִצְחָק֙

[Rashi there](http://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Genesis.31.42.1):

> ופחד יצחק. לא רצה לומר אלהי יצחק, שאין הקדוש ברוך הוא מיחד שמו על הצדיקים בחייהם, ואף על פי שאמר לו בצאתו מבאר שבע (לעיל כח יג) אני ה' אלהי אברהם אביך ואלהי יצחק, בשביל שכהו עיניו והרי הוא כמת, יעקב נתירא לומר אלהי ואמר ופחד:

He didn't want to say "אלוהי יצחק" out of respect for his father, who was still living, because Hashem doesn't usually associate his name with a Tzadik in their lifetime.

However, later ([32:9](http://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.32.9)), he does say

> אֱלֹהֵי֙ אָבִ֣י אַבְרָהָ֔ם וֵאלֹהֵ֖י אָבִ֣י יִצְחָ֑ק

Why the change in wording/attitude?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rashi himself asks and answers this question! On 32:9, [he writes](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8227/jewish/Chapter-32.htm#showrashi=true) that his purpose is to provide a direct quote of Hashem for the sake of his argument/plea:

> ואלהי אבי יצחק: ולהלן הוא אומר (לא מב) ופחד יצחק, ועוד מהו שחזר והזכיר שם המיוחד, היה לו לכתוב האומר אלי שוב לארצך וגו'. אלא כך אמר יעקב לפני הקב"ה שתי הבטחות הבטחתני אחת בצאתי מבית אבי מבאר שבע, שאמרת לי (כח יג) אני ה' אלהי אברהם אביך ואלהי יצחק, ושם אמרת לי (שם טו) ושמרתיך בכל אשר תלך. ובבית לבן אמרת לי (לא ג) שוב אל ארץ אבותיך ולמולדתך ואהיה עמך, ושם נגלית אלי בשם המיוחד לבדו, שנאמר (לא ג) ויאמר ה' אל יעקב שוב אל ארץ אבותיך וגו', בשתי הבטחות האלו אני בא לפניך:
>
> **and God of my father Isaac**: But elsewhere (31:42), it says: and the Fear of Isaac. Moreover, why did he repeat the Tetragrammaton? Scripture should have written: “Who said to me, ‘Return to your land, etc.’ ” Rather, so did Jacob say before the Holy One, blessed be He: You gave me two promises: one when I left my father’s house from Beer-sheba, when You said to me (28: 13): “I am the Lord, the God of Abraham your father, and the God of Isaac,” and there You said to me, (ibid., verse 15): “and I will guard you wherever you go.” And in Laban’s house You said to me (31:3), “Return to the land of your forefathers and to your birthplace, and I will be with you.” There You revealed Yourself to me with the Tetragrammaton alone, for it is said:“And the Lord (יהוה) said to Jacob, ‘Return to the land of your forefathers, etc.’” With these two promises I am coming before You.

Comment: Ah, i must have missed that Rashi. :)